# How to use React navigation as a component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Hello Guys am trying to use ViewCart file as a component in my project but its not showing , don't know why? but when I wrote it on whole code in my App.js file its working fine. please tell me why its happening, and also tell how to use Viewcart file as a component in in my project. if you have any query please free feel to ask.

// ViewCart.js

This file i want to use in my App.js file as a component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View >
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function ViewCart() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default ViewCart;
```

> App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import ViewCart from "./screens/ViewCart";

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ViewCart />
      {/* <StatusBar style="auto" /> */}
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // container: {
  //   flex: 1,
  //   backgroundColor: "#fff",
  //   alignItems: "center",
  //   justifyContent: "center",
  // },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this Solution Work.

Imp Points

1. NavigationContainer must wrap all navigators structure.
2. NavigationContainer will be add in the root of our app.

Just remove `NavigationContainer` from  `ViewCart.js` and add `NavigationContainer` in the `App.js`.

You can read official Doc :
[Click & Read Official Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#creating-a-native-stack-navigator)

**ViewCart.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native- stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
      <View >
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
 }

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function ViewCart() {
  return (
     <>
      <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
     </>
  );
 }

export default ViewCart;
```

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import ViewCart from "./ViewCart";

function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer style={styles.container}>
        <ViewCart />
        {/* <StatusBar style="auto" /> */}
      </NavigationContainer>
   );
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: "#fff",
   alignItems: "center",
   justifyContent: "center",
 },
});

export default App;
```

Hope this Will Work :)
[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@100rabhchavan/how-to-use-react-navigation-as-a-component)